# Subfigures not lining up horizontally

Tags: subfloats, subfig, sidewaysfigure

My two subfigures wont line up next to eachother, one is higher than the other. One doesn't need rotating but the other one does. When I rotate them both then they line up correctly but they don't otherwise.

This is the code I'm using which has worked for all my other figures.

Update: I have tried rotating the original picture outside LaTex but that doesn't seem to change anything.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include first image
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{Lill ex 2 3}  
  \caption{Our first solution.}
  \label{Lill fig:sub-first}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include second image
  \includegraphics[angle=270, width=0.8\linewidth]{Lill ex 2 5}  
  \caption{Finding more solutions. }
  \label{Lill fig:sub-second}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\caption{Second step of Lill's method for example \ref{example 2}.}
\label{Lill ex 2}
\end{figure}
```

[image: outcome attached]

Comment: Did you try with  `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}`?

Comment: Amazing thanks, that's solved it!

Answer (score 3):

As you suggested in your question already, the problem stems from rotating the second subfigure only, after which the baseline of the picture is not set to the 'new bottom' automatically.

However, instead of adjusting the position inside the `figure`, the simplest solution would be to turn the second picture outside of LaTeX, save the file, and then `\includegraphics` it without specifying the `angle` (since the picture looks like it should have that orientation anyways).

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `subfigure` positioning accordingly: from `t` to `b`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include first image
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{Lill ex 2 3}
  \caption{Our first solution.}
  \label{Lill fig:sub-first}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include second image
  \includegraphics[angle=270, width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{Lill ex 2 5}
  \caption{Finding more solutions. }
  \label{Lill fig:sub-second}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\caption{Second step of Lill's method for example \ref{example 2}.}
\label{Lill ex 2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\subcaptionbox`, that also copes with longer captions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\subcaptionbox{Our first solution.\label{Lill fig:sub-first}}[0.5\textwidth][c]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}%
}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Finding more solutions.\label{Lill fig:sub-second}}[0.5\textwidth][c]{%
  \includegraphics[angle=270, width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}%
}

\caption{Second step of Lill's method for example \ref{example 2}.}
\label{Lill ex 2}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one of the captions has to be longer than one line, the output would be like

[image]

However in this case something less than `0.5\textwidth` should be used or longer captions will clash with one another.